# Adding incremental relative position to dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create this shape using dynamically created divs. I have this code already in place:

```
var bgImg = ['ScreenShot.png', 'stars.jpg', 'ScreenShot.png', 'stars_1230_600x450.jpg'];

for (var i = 0, n = 12; i < n; i++) {
    var port = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(port);

port.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + bgImg[3] + "')";
```

I would like to create this image: https://flic.kr/p/mSJm6G

which will eventually hold images from the array. (one image per slot on the grid.)

I have tried below, which only does not work, it doesn't do what i want, which is to add that amount each time a new div is created. I want a new object to raise by 40px each time it is created.

```
$(port).css('top','+=40n');
```

I think that i will have to create three divs/scripts,, one for each row, so that i can get the divs to align properly. the master css will set the divs with a negative margin-top so they can cascade properly.

for reference, my css looks like this:

```
     div {
        height: 190px;
        width:230px;
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        background: #ef4c4d;
        background-position: center;
        float: left;
        margin: 8px;
        top: 30px;
        left: 10px;
    }

    div:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0; right: 0;
        border-bottom: 60px solid #0d1036;
        border-left: 60px solid transparent;
        width: 0;
    }
    div:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0;
        border-top: 60px solid #0d1036;
        border-right:60px solid transparent;
        width: 0;
    }
```

I think that i need to pull the integer from an array, but really not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Some things I notice in your code:

```
for (var i = 0, n = 12; i < n; i++) {
    var port = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(port);
// <- end "}" of for loop is missing here

port.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + bgImg[3] + "')"; // <- will just be applied on the last created div
```

I guess you want something like this:

```
for (var i = 0, n = 12; i < n; i++) {
    var port = document.createElement('div');
    port.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + bgImg[3] + "')";
    document.body.appendChild(port);
}
```

To update the "top" property, you can use this code with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
for (var i = 0, n = 12; i < n; i++) {
    var port = $('<div></div>');
    port.css("background-image", "url('" + bgImg[3] + "')");
    port.css("top": 40 * i + "px"); // <- set "top" +40px for each div
    $("body").append(port);
}
```

Comment: thanks for all your help! The code you supplied didn't quite work, but i modified it and magic!

        for (var i = 0, n = 4; i < n; i++) {
        var port = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(port);
        port.className = "port";

    port.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + bgImg[1] + "')";
    port.style.top =  (-40 * i + "px");
    }

Comment: Please have in mind, that my code just works, after you add jQuery to your HTML site. Good to know, that you finally find a solution. ;-)